# Semantic dictionary of English language

Tags: nlp, english

I am looking for a dictionary of English words tagged with their semantics. Like:

```
red      t:color
green    t:color
long     t:size     t:max
huge     t:size     t:max
tiny     t:size     t:min
hot      t:temp
cold     t:temp
...
```

Answer (score 4):

[Eurovoc](http://eurovoc.europa.eu/drupal/) is a large semantic "Multilingual Thesaurus of the European Union"

Comment: Downloaded it, but it's way too leveraged. I need something *more naïve*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) or some API like [wordnik](http://developer.wordnik.com/).

Comment: Could you extend your answer with a little information (link, basic functions, short pointer on how to find the semantic information there) about both services?

Comment: @ojdo Agree, that would be nice to have an extented info in the answer.